# Find the density function of the random variable

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with density function $f_{X}(x)=e^{-x}$ for $x>0$. I want to find the density function of the random variable $Y$ given by

$$
Y = \begin{cases}
    X & \text{if } X \leq 1 \\
    \frac{1}{X} & X>1
\end{cases}
$$

I think that the cumulative distribution function would be given by

$$F_{Y}(y)=P(Y \leq y)=\begin{cases}
    P(X \leq 1) & \text{if } y \leq 1 \\
    P(X >1)+ P(0 \leq \frac{1}{X} \leq y) & \text{if } y>1
\end{cases}$$

I think it might be an expression of that style, but I'm not entirely sure. My idea is that, once we have the cumulative distribution function of $Y$, we derive this and find the density function

But for this I would need the cumulative distribution function of the random variable $X$, which should be given by

$$\int_{-\infty}^{x} e^{-t}dt$$

But it appears that this integral diverges.

Another way could be to take $Y=h(X)$, if $h$ is a strictly monotone and differentiable function then we can write

$$f_{Y}(y)=\begin{cases}
    f_{X}(h^{-1}(y))\left| \frac{d}{dy} h^{-1}(y) \right| & \text{if } y>0 \\
    0 & y<0
\end{cases}
$$

Certainly the last way is more convenient, but it is not clear to me how to simplify the latter, any suggestions or comments? I will be grateful!

Comment: Why are you taking the lower bound of your CDF integral to be $-\infty$? You already specified that the domain of $f_X(x)$ is $x>0$.

Comment: That's right, then should I take $\int_{0}^{x} e^{-x}=1-e^{-x}$?

Comment: Also, how do you get the possibility of $y>1$?  $y$ will just be taking values between 0 and 1.

Comment: @JimB Well, I certainly put that without having much certainty, that's why I am looking for some correction or improvement with respect to it.

Comment: The problem with using the formula for a monotone transformation is that your function is not monotone :). When you encounter such transformations, you have to get a bit more hands-on. You may have seen such a problem if, for example, you've had to show that the square of a standard normal random variable is chi-squared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at the definition of $Y$, you can immediately see that if $X > 0$, then $0 < Y \le 1$.  This is because $Y = X$ whenever $X \le 1$, and when $X > 1$, then $1/X < 1$.

Next, observe
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[Y \le y] &= \Pr[X \le y \cap X \le 1] + \Pr[X > 1/y \cap X > 1]\\
&= \Pr[X \le \min(y,1)] + \Pr[X > \max(1,1/y)].
\end{align}$$

But since we already stipulated that $0 < Y \le 1$, then for any $y \in (0,1]$, the minimum of $y$ and $1$ is just $y$, and the maximum of $1$ and $1/y$ is $1/y$.  So
$$\Pr[Y \le y] = \Pr[X \le y] + \Pr[X > 1/y] = 1 - e^{-y} + e^{-1/y}, \quad 0 < y \le 1.$$
Differentiation yields the PDF:
$$f_Y(y) = e^{-y} + \frac{e^{-1/y}}{y^2}, \quad 0 < y \le 1.$$

Comment: Your answer has been very helpful, I have only one question left. What happens in any other case for $y$? is the value zero?

Comment: @Wrloord $$\Pr[Y \le 0] = 0, \quad \Pr[Y > 1] = 0.$$

Comment: Thank you, one last question and I am sorry to be insistent but $Pr[X>\frac{1}{y}]=\int_{\frac{1}{y}}^{?}e^{-x}$, What is the upper limit?

Comment: @Wrloord For any exponential random variable $X$, $$\Pr[X > x] = \int_{t=x}^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda t} \, dt.$$  The upper limit is infinity because the support of $X$ is the interval $(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the graph of the function $Y = g(X)$ as defined above:

[image]

Or rather, it's the graph of $g(X)$ plus some extra information.  Let's say we want $P(Y\le y)$.  The values of $X$ that yield such a $y$-value are shaded.  So you see, if $Y \le y$, then either $X \le y$ or $X \ge 1/y$.  In other words,

\begin{align}
P(Y \le y) &= P\left[(X\le y) \cup (X \ge 1/y) \right] \\
&= 1 - P(y < X < 1/y) \\
&= 1 - \left[ F_X(1/y) - F_X(y) \right],
\end{align}

where $F_X(\cdot)$ is the cdf of $X$.

Differentiating this expression with respect to $y$ will give us $f_Y(y)$.